# Detecting number of straps on coil using python image processing

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to detect the number of straps on coil which can be seen on the photo attached. I'm using python code and thought canny edge detection method would be OK for this. But I'm newbie for image processing and couldn't do yet.

Anyone can offer me some method or library or something else? I would be very appreciate. It should be done using Python. Thanks for helping.

[photo of coil with straps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oya4U.jpg)

Comment: *how many straps would you say are on that coil?* fundamentally, you need to take a better picture. that means different lighting and different angle/perspective. I'd recommend a complete course in computer vision/machine vision. you can't solve this without *some* education.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Yes, "how many straps are on that coil?" is better statement. Could you please recommend me a specific course? I'm asking this because there are a lot of stuff on web, but most of them is not useful or pro. And I'm running out my time :(

Comment: no, I am asking *you*, how many straps do *you* count on that coil? the four through the middle, the three around it, or all of them?

Comment: I need to detect all of them. So, in this photo I need to find out 7 straps as a return of python image processing application (sum of four through the middle, the three around it).

Comment: That task is very (too) difficult, due to uncontrolled conditions. Probably better to work on a picture from the side and one in front.